# Liquibase maven update command with parameter toTag

Tags: maven, liquibase

I have been trying to work with liquibase maven update command.

My scenario is this:

```
   1.  I have three versions of SQL in SVN.
   2.  I have already migrated to version 1.
   3.  Then I want to upgrade to version 2.
   4.  But don't want to apply version 3 migration.
   5.  With each version's changeset I use tagDatabase to tag database.
```

I went through maven update optional parameters. I found an optional parameter "toTag" and tried to use it. But the result is toTag parameter is not working as expected. Liquibase goes ahead with migration of version 3.

My maven configuration is below:

```
<profile>
    <id>migrate-change-log</id>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <verbose>${verbose}</verbose>
                            <toTag>${to.tag}</toTag>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to NOT deploy a particular changeset to a given environment, you would need to specify something that prevents that changeset from being deployed. The most common ways are using contexts or labels. For example, you might decide that a change is only appropriate for development or test environments, so you could put the attribute `context="dev OR test"` on that changeset. Then when you deploy you specify the context in the command : i.e. `context=dev` when deploying to the dev environment, and when you deploy to production you specify `context=prod`.

Tags are intended to 'mark' the database as having all changes for a specific version of the software the database works with, not as a way to control what changes are deployed.

Comment: I agree and currently I am using the labels to specify version, label="v1.0" and while deploying I will run all the change sets for label v1.0 and for environment I use context attribute. And at last use <tagDatabase> to tag the database. Is this the right way to go?? May be I am noy clear about this point, why tag record remains in database and what does "toTag" attribute mean? And how can I tell liquibase migrate from v1.0 to v2.0, if there are multiple versions available in source. Lables again, good approach??